# What are the various ways to protect the videos in browser?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I wanted to protect my video in browser. Nobody should be able to download the video. I have implemented the streaming with the help of node.js server. I'm displaying the video in html5 video player and I also have disabled the contextmenu of video player. But that isn't enough.
I still can download the video. I need your help to search options to protect the video in browser. I know this is public content but still this is doable and many companies are doing this.

Comment: You can not prevent “downloading”. The server doesn’t not know the difference if a web browser is downloading to play a video or if it’s downloading to store the video.

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for is known as DRM, or Digital Rights Management.

There are three main systems of DRM in use on the internet today. These are what all large video services such as Netflix use to protect their videos.

- **[Microsoft PlayReady](https://www.microsoft.com/playready/)**: Used in Microsoft Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge
- **[Google Widevine](https://www.widevine.com/)**: Used in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
- **[Apple FairPlay](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps)**: Used in Apple Safari

You can either build your own systems with these technologies from each vendor, or you can work with a service provider that handles all of them for you. Examples of providers would be [DRMToday](https://castlabs.com/drmtoday/), [BuyDRM](https://www.buydrm.com/), [PallyCon](https://www.pallycon.com/license-service/).